# Apache is logging failed calls to 'rm' using PHP's exec()

Tags: php, apache2, error-log

In order to clear cached versions of a page when they are edited, our CMS, written in PHP, uses exec() to get rid of all the relevant cache files. These files are always named so as to include the string '_lid45', say, where '45' is the unique identifier for that page.

The exec string will look something like

```
rm ../cache/*_lid45[._]*
```

and it works perfectly as long as there exist such files. If there aren't, then nothing goes wrong for the user, but the Apache error log gets a line like

```
rm: cannot remove `../cache/*_lid45[._]*': No such file or directory
```

I know this isn't the worst thing to happen! But I would like to try getting rid of the messages, without adding any more load to the original script, if I can. For instance, I thought about using 'ls' first to see if there were any such files, then only deleting them if they were present, but since the size of the cache can sometimes be considerable, 'ls' can occasionally slow down to the point where it has a noticeable effect on the performance of the whole server!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just send the output of `rm` to `/dev/null`:

```
exec("rm ../cache/*_lid45['_]* > /dev/null 2>&1");
```

And it will suppress all the output, which should suppress the errors.

If you don't know much/anything about output redirection, you might find [this](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles2/042.html) to be worth a read...